# saving and retrieve core data from server

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, restkit

I'm planing to use core data to store my data. I want the user to add some data or update some data that have been added previously by him. I'm going to use a server to save the core data on it, I've read some question here and the answer was to use RESTKit. but I'm not sure if it's the right choice or not, my question is it simple to do what I said before about save the data and retrieve it from server by using a core data? and please if any one have a tutorial for me that will explain lot of things to me like my Idea :/

i did the design and I have now core data with all the entities like user entity and photo entity.

I hope I made my question clear >_< and Thank you for reading my question :$

Answer (score 1):

I like AFNetworking.  If you write your web-services to work with JSON, this is a great choice IMO.  If you are using XML based web-services and don't want to / can't change to JSON, then TBXML is a great choice for parsing XML.

Comment: Thank you, i'll see what those are ^_^